# Button to imitate UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, size, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the UIBarButtonItems to trigger special actions but I also want to add another button on the bottom part of the screen with the same dimensions as the ones created in the NavigationBar, how could I do this?

Can I do it in the Interface Builder with some fixed width/height constrains or do I have to do it programatically, if so could you give me an example?

Thank you

Comment: Deyton's answer is correct. If you don't want to have a bar at the bottom of your view you can make it transparent by setting it's background to a transparent image `toolbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .Bottom, barMetrics: .Default)` and setting its shadow image to a transparent image `toolbar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .Bottom)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a [`UIToolbar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIToolbar.html) to the bottom of the view. If your view controller is in a `UINavigationController`, the best way to do this would be to add the bar button items, either in Interface Builder by drag-and-drop or programmatically using [`setToolbarItems`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setToolbarItems:animated:).